# Define setter for Maps in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Assume I have this property in a class:

```
private var dates: Map<String, Long?> = mapOf(
    "creation" to System.currentTimeMillis(),
    "lastUpdate" to System.currentTimeMillis()
)
```

Now, I need to update "lastUpdate" timestamp using function below:

```
fun start(): Boolean {
    this.dates["lastUpdate"] = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return true
}
```

I get this Error:

"No set method providing array access"

How should I define setter and getter methods for maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin's [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) is immutable, i.e. you neither can edit any values in it nor you can add any new values.

In Kotlin there is seperate interface that does give you `operator fun get()` and `operator fun set()` in it, it is actually a [MutableMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/), an extension to the `Map`.

You can create MutableMap using the [mutableMapOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-map-of.html) function in the standard library.

```kotlin
private var dates: MutableMap<String, Long?> = mutableMapOf(
    "creation" to System.currentTimeMillis(),
    "lastUpdate" to System.currentTimeMillis()
)

// Then change whatever you want to
dates["lastUpdate"] = System.currentTimeMillis()
```